# What can cause the corruption of Windows menus appearance?

Tags: windows, debugging, gdi

I have a problem with a system: sometimes it shows corrupt menus like these:

[image: corrupt menu from right click on Taskbar]
[image: corrupt menu from task manager]

The first image is from the contextual menu which appears right clicking on the Taskbar, the second image is from the Task Manager and so we are talking about applications made by Microsoft.

There are three corrupt parts: the "check mark", the "black right-pointing triangle" and the "black circle", all of them have two black horizontal line (the width of the line is 1 pixel).

Is it a font related problem? I do not know if these parts are Unicode characters or not.

The problem is sporadic and I have no clues on how to solve it.

Is there any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is a graphics device driver bug. Try updating your drivers or perhaps sticking in a different card if you have one spare.

Comment: +1 Thank you! I will try to look for an updated device driver.